# Perl New Line separator issue

Tags: perl, newline

I have a file that uses CR/LF to separate records, but individual records sometimes contain a LF.

```
while (<$in>)
{ 
    #extract record data
}
```

I am trying to read this code as above and this (as I would expect) splits the records that contain a LF only. I would however have expected that a reassigned [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/) would resolve this issue but it does appear to cause the complete file to me read in one iteration.

```
$/ = "\r\n";
while (<$in>)
{ 
    #extract record data
}
```

Anyone here who can suggest a working solution?

I am using Activestate Perl on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this before while

```
binmode($in);
```

Answer (score 11):

On windows, perl converts the incoming CRLF line endings to LF only, making a distinction between CRLF and LF impossible by reading in the data as text ([perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines)). Therefore, you have to read your data in binary mode using [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on your file-handle:

```
binmode($in);
```

After that, you can set the input record separator to "\015\012" and read-in your records as usual:

```
$/ = "\015\012";
while (<$in>) {
    ...
}
```

greets, Matthias

PS: I have no chance to test that locally, at the moment, so I regret if it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `$/` to `"\n"`. From [Newlines in perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines):

> Perl uses `\n` to represent the "logical" newline, where what is logical
>   may depend on the platform in use. In MacPerl, `\n` always means `\015`.
>   In DOSish perls, `\n` usually means `\012`, but when accessing a file in
>   "text" mode, perl uses the `:crlf` layer that translates it to (or from)
>   `\015\012`, depending on whether you're reading or writing.