# Perl cannot close files on Windows?

Tags: perl, winapi, io, handle, filehandle

I am encountering a very strange behavior.

My Perl program is trying to close some files on Windows. It turns out that the files do not close - and there is no error message.

How do I know that the files do not get closed? Because when trying to Perl "move" function on them, it gives the errors:

$!: Permission denied

$^E: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I have tested this program on two different computers, one running Windows XP SP 3, and the other Windows 7 - getting *identical* results.

When I "clobber" the files using the Windows "handle.exe" utility, then the files do get closed, and I can "move" (rename) the files.

(I am sorry that this question is lengthy, but otherwise responders may say that there isn't enough detail to understand the issues).

Here are the code examples.

In this program, if the user chooses "yes" "force_close", the sub force_close is called, and the files do get closed. If the user chooses "no", then it's only the Perl program calling the "close" function on these two *.csv files, and actually they stay open! ("close" returns with no errors!)

Important note: no other process is using the files, or holding them open. (Neither a possible "anti virus"). How do I know? Because the "force_close" subroutine does succeed in closing the files, using a single Windows handle connected to the perl.exe process; if another process kept the files open, then there should have been an additional open handle for that file, and Perl "move" function would fail.

Explanatory notes:
a. File information is held in simple hashes, containing the file handle and the mode, (in addition to the file name).

b. Subroutine YNChoice is a simple radio button yes/no choice window.

The main program:

```
use strict;
 use warnings;
 use 5.014; 
 use Win32::GUI();
 use Win32::Console;
 use autodie; 
 use warnings qw< FATAL utf8 >;
 use Carp;
 use Carp::Always;
 use File::Copy;
 use File::stat;
 use English '-no_match_vars';

my ($i, $j, $k, $sta, $desk, $dw, $dh, $filename, $filename_old, $MovedFileName, $resname_new,
        $resH, $inpH, $TopDir, $InputDir, $pid, $stobj, $fmode, $debug, $forceclose_choice);
my $NL = "\x0A";
my ( %inp_file, %res_file, %log);
sub force_close;
state $prog_name = substr( ProgName(), rindex(ProgName(), '\\')+1);
binmode STDOUT, ':unix:utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':unix:utf8';
binmode $DB::OUT, ':unix:utf8' if $DB::OUT; # for the debugger
Win32::Console::OutputCP(65001);         # Set the console code page to UTF8
$debug = TRUE;
$TopDir = 'E:\My Documents\Technical\Perl\Eclipse workspace';
$desk = Win32::GUI::GetDesktopWindow();
$dw = Win32::GUI::Width($desk);
$dh = Win32::GUI::Height($desk);
$InputDir = Win32::GUI::BrowseForFolder( -root => $TopDir, -includefiles => 1,
                    -title => 'Select directory for file to rename', -newui => 1, 
                    -text =>'text Select directory for file', -size => [60/100*$dw, 60/100*$dh],
                    -position =>  [50/100*$dw, 50/100*$dh], -owner =>$desk);
$log{FileName} = $InputDir.'\Close file test log '.DatenTime().'.txt';
$i = OpenFile \%log, ">:encoding(utf8)",    # Must open log.txt explicitly
            TimeString().SP.ProgName().": opening file: \n".$log{FileName};
if ($i) {
    PrintT $log{HANDLE}, TimeString().SP.ProgName().": opened file '$log{FileName}'";
}   # end if ($i)
binmode $i, ':unix:utf8';
# Select test file to open
$filename = Win32::GUI::GetOpenFileName( -title  => 'Select file to open and close with handle',
        -directory => $InputDir, -file   => "\0" . " " x 256,
        -filter => ["All files", "*.*", "Text files (*.txt)" => "*.txt",],
        -text => 'Select file');
$inp_file{FileName} = $filename;
$inpH = OpenFile \%inp_file, "<:encoding(utf8)",    
            TimeString().SP.$prog_name.": opening file:\n'$inp_file{FileName};";
binmode $inpH, ':unix:utf8';
if ($inpH) { #1
    say ": opened file:\n'$inp_file{FileName}'";
}   # end if ($inpH)
else { #1
    confess "Opening file '$inp_file{FileName}' failed";
} #1 end else if ($inpH)

$j = rindex $inp_file{FileName}, '.';
$res_file{FileName} = substr($inp_file{FileName}, 0, $j).' res.csv';
$resH = OpenFile \%res_file, '>:encoding(utf8)', 
                ": opening \$res_file for output:\n'$res_file{FileName}'";
binmode $resH, ':unix:utf8';
local $/ = "\x0D\x0A";
while (<$inpH>) { #1
    chomp;
    $i = $_;
    s{^(.*)(?<!\x0D)\x0A(.*)$}{$1$2}g;  # delete newlines not preceded by cr
                                                    # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391721
                                                    # and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines
    $i = $_;
    PrintT $resH, $_;
}   #1 end while (<$inpH>)

CloseFile \%inp_file, TimeString(), SP, $prog_name, ": closing file: \n",
                                                                                    $inp_file{FileName};
CloseFile \%res_file, TimeString(), SP, $prog_name, ": closing file: \n", $res_file{FileName};

${^WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT} = TRUE;   # see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat
$stobj = stat $inp_file{FileName};
$fmode =  sprintf "%04o", $stobj->mode & 07777;
say ": for file \$inp_file{FileName}:\n'$inp_file{FileName}'\n",
    'Mode is: ', $fmode, ', $stobj->mode = ', $stobj->mode;
$forceclose_choice = YNChoice Question => 'force_close $inp_file and $res_file?',
                                        Debug => $debug, SizeRef => [30,15], LogRef => \%log;
if ($forceclose_choice) { #1
    $pid = $PID;
    force_close FileName => $inp_file{FileName}, owning_process => $pid, LogRef => \%log,
            Debug => $debug;
}  #1
$filename_old = substr($inp_file{FileName}, 0, $j).' old.csv';
say ": moving file:\n", "'$inp_file{FileName}' to:\n", "'$filename_old'\n";
$sta = move $inp_file{FileName}, $filename_old;
unless ($sta) { #1
    confess "\n", $prog_name, ": problem renaming incoming file to '*.old'\n",
                                                                                        "\$!: $!\n", "\$^E: $^E";
} #1 end unless ($sta)
else { PrintDebug $debug, \%log, $prog_name, ': moving succeeded'; }
$resname_new = substr($inp_file{FileName}, 0, $j).'.csv'; # the original incoming filename
$inp_file{FileName} = $filename_old;
if ($forceclose_choice) { #1
    force_close FileName => $res_file{FileName}, owning_process => $pid, LogRef => \%log,
                Debug => $debug;
}  #1
say ": renaming file:\n", "'$res_file{FileName}' to:\n", "'$resname_new'\n";
$sta = move $res_file{FileName}, $resname_new;
unless ($sta) {  #1
        confess $prog_name, ": problem renaming ResFile to original\n", "\$!: $!\n", "\$^E: $^E";
} #1 end unless ($sta)
else { say ': moving succeeded'; }
$res_file{FileName} = $resname_new;
```

Subroutines OpenFile and CloseFile:

```
sub OpenFile {      # Call: OpenFile \%FileStruct, $Mode, $Message [,$Message ...];
    my ($FileRef, $Mode) =@_[0..1];
    my ($HANDLE, $FileName, $sta);
    $FileName = $FileRef->{FileName};
    if (@_ >=3) { #1
        foreach (@_[2..(scalar @_-1)]) { #2
            print $_;
        }   #2 end foreach (@_[2..(scalar @_ -1)])
        print "\n";
    }   #1 end if (@_ >=3)
    unless ( defined $FileName) { confess 'Utilities::OpenFile: $FileName undefined';}
    elsif ($Mode =~ m{.*<.*}) { #1 
        unless (-e $FileName) { #2
            confess "Utilities::OpenFile: file '$FileName' does not exist'";
        }   #2 end unless (-e $FileName)
    }   #1 end elsif (! defined $FileName)
    unless ( defined $FileRef->{HANDLE} and defined openhandle($FileRef->{HANDLE}) 
                and defined $FileRef->{Mode} and ($FileRef->{Mode} =~ m{^.*<.*$})) { #1
        $sta = open ($HANDLE, $Mode, $FileName);
        if ($sta) { #2
            $FileRef->{HANDLE} = $HANDLE;
            $FileRef->{Mode} = $Mode;
        } else { #2
            confess "Can't open \$HANDLE: file:\n'$FileName'\n\$!: $!\n\$^E: $^E"; 
        }    #2 end else if ! $sta
    } #1 end unless (if not) file is open
    else { #1 file is open
        say ' called from ', CallerName(),': file ', $FileRef->{FileName},' is open';
        $sta = TRUE;
    } #1 end else file is open
    return ($sta ? $HANDLE : $sta);
  }  # end sub OpenFile

sub CloseFile { # Call: CloseFile \%FileStruct, $Message [,$Message ...];
    my $FileRef = shift;
    my ($HANDLE, $FileName, $sta);
    $FileName = $FileRef->{FileName};
    if (@_ >=1) { #1  There is a message
        foreach (@_) { #2
            print $_;
        }   #2 end foreach (@_[1..(scalar @_ -1)])
        print "\n";
    }   #1 end if (@_ >=3)
    unless (-e $FileName) { #1
        confess SubName().": file '$FileName' does not exist'";
    }   #1 end unless (-e $FileName)
    unless ( defined $FileName) { confess SubName().': $FileName undefined';}
    unless (defined openhandle($FileRef->{HANDLE})) { #1
        say ": file $FileName is closed!";
        $sta = 0;                                                   
    } else {  #1
        $sta = close $FileRef->{HANDLE};
        unless ( $sta) {  #2
            confess "Can't close \$HANDLE: file:\n'$FileName'\n\$!: $!\n\$^E: $^E";
        } else {  #2
            undef $FileRef->{Mode};
        }  #2 end else $sta
    } #1 end else defined handle
    return $sta;
} # end sub CloseFile
```

Subroutine force_close:

```
sub force_close { # close $FileStruct{FileName} using MS handle -------------------- force_close
# call: $sta = force_close FileName => $file_name, owning_process => $pid, LogRef = \%Log,
#               Debug = $debug;
my %parms = @_;
my ($i, $j, $sta, $stobj, $fmode, $HANDLE, $command, $pid, $Windows_handle, $filename,
            $filename_reg, $file_line, $lineno, $file_lineno, $s1succ, $s2succ);
my @handle_output;
state $handleloc = '"E:\\WinXP Programs\\System\\Utilities\\handle"';  #Location of MS handle.exe
local $/ = "\x0A";
# get all open files for the perl process
$pid = $parms{owning_process};
$filename = $parms{FileName};
$filename_reg = qr{\Q$filename\E};
$sta = open $command, "$handleloc -p $pid |";
unless ($sta) { #1
    confess "\n", SubName(), ': problem invoking handle command',
                                                                                    "\$!: $!\n", "\$^E: $^E";
} #1 end unless ($sta)
$lineno = 0;
while (<$command>) {
    chomp;
    $j = $_;
    if (m{$filename_reg} ) {
        $file_line = $_;
        $file_lineno = $lineno;
    }   # end if (m{$filename_reg} )
    push @handle_output, $_;
    say "\$lineno = $lineno\n", $_;
    ++$lineno;
} # end while (<$command>)
close $command;

if  (defined $file_line) { # 1
    say ': found line with $parms{FileName}, no.:', $file_lineno, ", Line:\n'$file_line'";
    # get handle number for the file we want to close
    $file_line =~ m{^\s*(\w+)\:};
    unless (defined $1) { confess '$1 not defined'};
    $Windows_handle = defined $1 ? $1 : '';
    @handle_output = ();    # release array
    # force close the file
    $sta = open $command, "$handleloc -c $Windows_handle -p $pid -y |";
    unless ($sta) { #1
        confess "\n", SubName(), ': problem invoking handle command',
                                                                                        "\$!: $!\n", "\$^E: $^E";
    } #1 end unless ($sta)
    while (<$command>) {
        chomp;
        $j = $_;
        push @handle_output, $_;
        PrintDebug $parms{Debug}, $parms{LogRef}, $_;
    } # end while (<$command>)
    close $command;
}  # 1  end if (defined $file_line)
else  { #1 
    say ': couldn\'t find match for {FileName}, $file_line not defined',
                "\n", '@handle_output =', scalar @handle_output, ", \$pid= $pid";
    confess '';
}   # end else (! defined $file_line)
}   # end sub force_close
```

subroutines YNCoice and TerminateWindow:

```
sub YNChoice { # Ask a yes/no question, in a 2 radio boxes window  
        # call: $answer = YNChoice (Question => $Question, SizeRef => \@Size,
        #       PosRef => \@Pos, (in percentages), LogRef => \%Log, Debug => $Debug); 
        #       Size and Pos (in percent of desktop) are optional
my %parms = @_;
my ($i, $j, $k, $desk, $w, $h, $WindowChoice, $wPCT, $hPCT, $deskw, $deskh, $x, $y, $xPCT, $yPCT);
my $wPCTmin =20; my $hPCTmin = 15;
my @UserChoice;
$desk = Win32::GUI::GetDesktopWindow();
$deskw = Win32::GUI::Width($desk);
$deskh = Win32::GUI::Height($desk);
$xPCT = (defined $parms{PosRef}[0] and $parms{PosRef}[0] >=0 and $parms{PosRef}[0] <=100) ?
                ($parms{PosRef}[0]) : 20;
$yPCT = (defined $parms{PosRef}[1] and $parms{PosRef}[1] >=0 and $parms{PosRef}[1] <=100) ?
                ($parms{PosRef}[1]) : 20;
$wPCT = (defined $parms{SizeRef}[0] and $parms{SizeRef}[0] >=0 and $parms{SizeRef}[0] <=100) ?
                $parms{SizeRef}[0] : 20;
$wPCT = $wPCT >= $wPCTmin ? $wPCT : $wPCTmin;
$hPCT = (defined $parms{SizeRef}[1] and $parms{SizeRef}[1] >=0 and $parms{SizeRef}[1] <=100) ?
                $parms{SizeRef}[1] : 12;
$hPCT = $hPCT >= $hPCTmin ? $hPCT : $hPCTmin;
$WindowChoice = Win32::GUI::Window->new( -name => 'choice', -text => $parms{Question},
        -pos => [$xPCT/100*$deskw, $yPCT/100*$deskh], 
        -size => [$wPCT/100*$deskw,$hPCT/100*$deskh], -dialogui => 1,
        -onTerminate => \&TerminateWindow, -tabstop => 1,
        -addexstyle => WS_EX_TOPMOST, -cancel => 1, );
$WindowChoice -> AddRadioButton ( -name => 'ButtonRadioYes', -pos => [10,10],
                        -size => [20,20], -onClick => sub { &RadioClickYes(\@UserChoice) });
$WindowChoice -> AddLabel (-name => 'LabelRadioYes', -text=> 'Yes', -pos => [30,10],
                        -size => [40,20]);
$WindowChoice -> AddRadioButton ( -name => 'ButtonRadioNo', -pos => [10,40],
                        -size => [20,20], -onClick => sub { &RadioClickNo(\@UserChoice) });
$WindowChoice -> AddLabel (-name => 'LabelRadioNo', -text=> 'No', -pos => [30,40],
                        -size => [40,20]);
$WindowChoice ->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();
TerminateWindow();
return $UserChoice[0];
} # end sub YNChoice

sub TerminateWindow {
    return -1;
} # end sub TerminateWindow
```

Subroutines RadioClickYes and RadioClickNo:

```
sub RadioClickYes {
    $_[0][0] = 1;
    TerminateWindow();
} # end sub RadioClickYes

sub RadioClickNo {
    $_[0][0] = 0;
    TerminateWindow();
} # end sub RadioClickNo
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could figure out what exactly the problem is so that we don't have to go through all that code...

Comment: agreed; some work cutting down the code to the bare minimum that exhibits the problem would really help

Comment: maybe a silly question, but what *is* force_close?

Comment: @eckes: the problem is that the two csv files do not get closed by the Perl "close" function, but they do get closed using the Windows "handle.exe" executable.

Comment: @ysth: force_close is a subroutine (listed in the question) which calls the Windows utility "handle.exe", finds a file's Windows handle, and uses it to close the file.

Comment: That code is too messy and lengthy to expect us to troubleshoot.  Your stating point would be run your code through Perl::Tidy to clean up the formatting and then Perl::Critic to learn about some of the problem areas.  Once that is done, then post back with more refined (reduced) code.

Comment: BTW, close should populate $! if it fails.  It would be a good idea to inspect that when a failure occurs.

Comment: Are you really sure that you've got the correct file? It would take effort to not be able to close a file that you've already got open.

Comment: @Ron Bergin: close returns '1'. But, like I said, when trying to rename the file (with move), it fails.

Comment: @Len Jaffe: when I use the Perl close function, it returns normally (as if the file was closed ok). The problem is, it didn't _really_ get closed. It only gets closed when I hit it with the Windows utility handle.exe. (It's all there in the OP).

Comment: Are you certain it's Perl that has the file open?  Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896653) to find the process that has the file open.

Comment: @cjm: thank you, that's a good idea - I'll try it and report. But, IMO, it must be Perl that has the file open: note this: the subroutine force_close issues two calls to the Windows handle.exe utility. The first one looks for, and lists all open (Windows) handles belonging to "Perl.exe". _The file is found there_. Then it issues a second call to handle.exe, telling it to close the file - and it does. Conclusion: it's Perl holding the file open. But I'll try inspecting with process explorer and report here.

Comment: _@cjm: I've used process explorer. Result: it's Perl holding the two *.csv files open. (More detail: I kept the program suspended simply by not choosing a radio button when the "YNChoice" window is up; then in process explorer, searched for '.csv'. Result: it's the perl.exe process (and no other process) having those two files open). @cjm: thank you for this good debugging idea. So, back to the main question: how come Perl returns from the "close" function with a '1', no errors, but doesn't actually close the files??

Comment: @HelenCraigman - Did you ever get a solution to this? I've noticed that Perl sometimes doesn't close filehandles and never found a suitable solution. It seems to occur more frequently in multithreaded code and also with files >1GB, but I've never been able to replicate the issue consistently

Comment: @Simon: no, I never got a solution; and I stopped using Perl a while ago, and moved to python.

Answer (score -1):

Each time you call OpenFile and successfully open the file, you are creating 2 filehandles, but you only close one of them.

Here are the key individual lines of code in OpenFile.

Here is the first filehandle:

> $sta = open ($HANDLE, $Mode, $FileName);

Here's where you dup it:

> $FileRef->{HANDLE} = $HANDLE;

Here you're returning the first one:

> return ($sta ? $HANDLE : $sta);

Here's the calling of the sub

> $i = OpenFile \%log, ">:encoding(utf8)", ....

So, now you have one handle in $i and the second one in $log{HANDLE}

Comment: _Ron: thank you for investing the time to understand the code. But, what your'e saying is incorrect. Here's why: since $FileRef->{HANDLE} is identical to $HANDLE (and $i is identical to $HANDLE), therefore when you invoke 'close' (in sub CloseFile) on the handle (namely, on $FileRef->{HANDLE}), the handle is supposed to get closed (all three, since they contain the same value). Saying it in other words: $FileRef->{HANDLE}, $HANDLE and $i are not different handles, they are the same handle.